# How can I use dial-up internet in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking

I want to convert from windows to ubuntu. I use a dial-up internet connection. In windows, it is very easy to setup a dialup connection. But in ubuntu 12.04 (run from livecd) I found no option to setup a dialup internet connection. I read other tutorials but I couldn't understand them clearly. It would be very helpful for me if anyone can give me a step to step tutorial. It is holding me back from installing ubuntu because I work online most of the time. I'm also a noob so please use easy language :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your network manager for the option to add a dial up connection.  Right click the icon in the system tray and click "Edit Connections".  There's all kinds of options in there for setting up new connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually not at all hard once you're pointed in the right direction.

[Here is an article which should get you all the way  there](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/setting-up-dial-up-connection-in-ubuntu.html). <- Click Here!!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your link. now i know how to set up a dial up connetion in ubuntu. but it is still complicated for me. i need to find out some more info like if i need to use something else instead of "ogin" and "ssword". so much for simplicity of ubuntu and linux :( the vast number of broadband connections doesn't mean dial ups are extinct. specially in a third world country like bangladesh.